# CJK corruption, sqlite3

Tags: unicode, sqlite, cjk, utf

These two methods are used for encrypting / decrypting DB content:

```
public String encrypt(String str) {
    try {
        // Encode the string into bytes using utf-8
        byte[] utf8 = str.getBytes("UTF8");

        // Encrypt
        byte[] enc = ecipher.doFinal(utf8);

        // Encode bytes to base64 to get a string
        return Base64.encodeToString(enc, Base64.NO_WRAP);

    } catch (javax.crypto.BadPaddingException e) {
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    }
    return null;
}

public String decrypt(String str) {
    try {
        // Decode base64 to get bytes
        byte[] dec = Base64.decode(str, Base64.NO_WRAP);

        // Decrypt
        byte[] utf8 = dcipher.doFinal(dec);

        // Decode using utf-8
        return new String(utf8, "UTF8");
    } catch (javax.crypto.BadPaddingException e) {
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    }
    return null;
}
```

I have manually checked that the raw byte arrays getting encrypted/decrypted are the same, yet somehow, the CJK strings manage to corrupt. For instance, Korean "유료컨텐츠는 63" gets garbled into [image]. I could only think about the space character in the original text screwing up everything... but it sounds foolish. Same garbling observed on bot Android device and SQlite browser UI. I have been fiddling with UTF 8 / 16 all day and do not think it is related to the issue at hand. The garbled outcome still looks Korean to my eye... Any hints please ?

EDIT: this is how the utf8 byte array looks like in both methods:

```
[0] -61 [195] [0xc3]    
[1] -126 [130] [0x82]   
[2] -27 [229] [0xe5]    
[3] -116 [140] [0x8c]   
[4] -125 [131] [0x83]   
[5] -24 [232] [0xe8]    
[6] -127 [129] [0x81]   
[7] -124 [132] [0x84]   
[8] -29 [227] [0xe3]    
[9] -66 [190] [0xbe]    
[10]    -103 [153] [0x99]   
[11]    -26 [230] [0xe6]    
[12]    -108 [148] [0x94]   
[13]    -96 [160] [0xa0]    
[14]    54 [0x36]   
[15]    51 [0x33]
```

Comment: What are the actual bytes of the garbled message and the proper message?

Comment: the utf8 byte array in both methods for that sample origina string is: [-61, -126, -27, -116, -125, -24, -127, -124, -29, -66, -103, -26, -108, -96, 49, 49]

Comment: sorry, last 2 bytes are 0x36 0x33

Comment: What are the negative numbers, 2s compliment or what? Could you convert to unsigned, please?

Comment: Also, how can the bytes be the same in both cases? Either the decoding or the bytes must be different if you get a different result.

Comment: updated the question.. clearly there is something else in the middle. Pretty elusive too!

Comment: To save others the job of editing the columns, here are the hex bytes: `c3 82 e5 83 e8 81 84 e3 be 99 e6 94 a0 36 33`

Comment: C3 82 in UTF-8 is U+00C2 and should display as Â so it appears that both renderings are wrong, or this is not UTF-8 at all. The sequences do look like UTF-8 so I'm guessing you have an invalid transcoding from something else.